# Laravel Eloquent where clause on relationship with joining relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to show **all** users with their point values between dates. The point values need to between a start date and end date range. The problem I'm having is I have a `ActivityName` model that joins to the `ActivityPoints` to show the category name. I've always known to add a where clause within the join for something like this but I'm not sure where the joining relationship will fall.

```
$SalesReps = User::with('ActivityPoints', function ($query) use ($StartDate, $EndDate) {
                $query->where('created_at', '>=', $StartDate);
                $query->where('created_at', '<=', $EndDate);
            }, 'ActivityPoints.ActivityName')
            ->whereIn('id', $SalesRepsData->pluck('id')->toArray())
            ->get();
```

This returns the error:
`mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Obviously, I can do something like:

```
$SalesReps = User::with('ActivityPoints', 'ActivityPoints.ActivityName')
            ->whereHas('ActivityPoints', function ($query) use ($StartDate, $EndDate) {
                $query->where('created_at', '>=', $StartDate);
                $query->where('created_at', '<=', $EndDate);
            })
            ->whereIn('id', $SalesRepsData->pluck('id')->toArray())
            ->get();
```

but it won't show the users with zero points (null values).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a bracket around it and it worked.. strange.

```
     $SalesReps = User::with(['ActivityPoints' => function ($query) use ($StartDate, $EndDate) {
            $query->where('created_at', '>=', $StartDate);
            $query->where('created_at', '<=', $EndDate);
        }], 'ActivityPoints.ActivityName')
        ->whereIn('id', $SalesRepsData->pluck('id')->toArray())
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**WhereBetween** option could work

```
$SalesReps = User::with('ActivityPoints', 'ActivityPoints.ActivityName')
    ->whereHas('ActivityPoints', function ($query) use ($StartDate, $EndDate) {
        $query->whereBetween('created_at', array($StartDate,$EndDate));
      })
    ->whereIn('id', $SalesRepsData->pluck('id')->toArray())
    ->get();
```

Comment: While the `WhereBetween` is a good tip instead of the double where - it doesn't solve my issue. As seen in my question, using this answer will hide users without any point data.

Comment: And using "  User::->leftjoin() " did you try it ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I would strongly prefer to use a model.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
$SalesReps = User::with('ActivityPoints', function ($query) use ($StartDate, $EndDate) {
                $query->where('created_at', '>=', $StartDate)
                ->where('created_at', '<=', $EndDate);
            }, 'ActivityPoints.ActivityName')
            ->whereIn('id', $SalesRepsData->pluck('id')->toArray())
            ->get();
```

Comment: I tried this too .. Returns, `mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`.